# Problem with the '.style.transform=' in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this SVG header that, on screen scroll, its parts move differently. For this, I am using a script like the following:

```
let menu = document.getElementById('main-menu');
let lua = document.getElementById('lua');
            
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        let value = window.scrollY;
        menu.style.marginTop = value * 0.45 + 'px'; // working just fine
        lua.style.transform = "translateY(" + value * 0.25 + ")"; // don't know how to make this work
```

*OBS: I need to use the transform: translate because this SVG element, for some reason, can't be moved with margin or top/left, only translate.*

The **menu.style** work just fine, but on the **lua.style** case I'm struggling cause I don't know how to write on the JS a CSS such as transform: translateY that merges a child property (translate) inside another property (transform).

I've tried to write the `lua.style.transform = "translateY(" + value * 0.25 + ")";`  in many different ways, like:

```
lua.style.transform = value + "translateY(" * 0.25 + ")";
// or
lua.style.translate = value * 0.45 + 'px';
// or
lua.style.translate = value * 0.45;
// or
lua.style.translate = (0,value * 0.45);
```

but still can't make it work. How can I write it correctly?

Comment: Have you tried using template literals?

Comment: Template Literals? Never heard of. Gonna search here.

Comment: Add a working snippit of what you have tried, you will likely get an answer much quicker.

Comment: A [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) Template literals are literals delimited with backticks ` ` , allowing embedded expressions called substitutions. This allows you to concatenate strings and variables/code together  Like this:    **lua.style.transform = ` translateY(*${value * 0.25}* ) `**.

Comment: Please provide an example of the exact value you want to store in the `.transform` property. Also, doesn't `transformY()` require a unit of measurement? If so, you should be specifying, e.g. `"translateY(" + value * 0.25 + "px)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DONE! I used the template literal that Dane Landry explained in the comments. Thanks man.

The code:

```
lua.style.transform = ` translateY(${value * 0.25}px ) `;
```

And also thanks kmoser for reminding me translate demans a unit of measurement. It does.